# JSON Create a unique link

Tags: html, json

Sorry for the wrong use of tags, this is my first post here so I'm not used to how it's working.
I'll try to be more specific:

I have a couple of objects like this:

```
var products = [
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Chair",
    "thumbnail": "img/products/1.jpg"
}, 

{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Car",
    "thumbnail": "img/products/2.jpg"
}
```

And then I write them to a div named "objects":

```
document.getElementById("objects").innerHTML =

    '<div class="item">' + 
    '<a id="fade" href="#">' + '<img src=' + products[0].thumbnail + ' /></a>' + 
    "<br>" + products[0].name  + '</a>' + '</div>' + 

    '<div class="item">' + 
    '<a id="fade_2" href="#">' + '<img src=' + products[1].thumbnail + ' /></a>' + 
    "<br>" + products[1].name  + '</a>' + '</div>' ;
```

What I want is when I click on an image, the images disappear and another div is visible instead like this:

```
$("#fade").click(function(){
 $("#content").fadeOut(400);
   $("#obj_1").fadeIn(400); });
```

I hope I've been more detailed of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: ...and show more code, please.

Comment: img src will take the image from a loation. For the link to work either a href should be set to a page or function or there should be onclick() method set.

Comment: Let me confirm with you, you want buttons to cause their corresponding images to appear on the main div? Like a gallery type thing?

Comment: Almost, I want the images themselves act as buttons, or links. But yes it's like a gallery with thumbnails and when you click a thumbnail, you get the detailed information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what i understood I think you mean something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/w7sL4b6y/

I made it using lists because I fail to see the practicality of loading them in arrays unless you want to load them asynchronously, which I also don't see why you would. So let me know if this is what you are looking for.

So the unordered lists are for the galleries (Also set the the image sizes in css)

```
  <ul id="gallery">
     <li><a><img></a></li> // One image entry
  </ul>
```

And they will appear in the spectacle div when selected

```
 <div id="spectacle"></div>
```

(This is as per my jsfiddle)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I think I understand your fiddle, but the problem is that I declare my images in the script-tags and they are displayed correctly, the only thing that is not working is to make the images to links. Is there anyway I can add this to the code I already got? I mean to make the images in the script-tags clickable?

Comment: Actually, I think I solved it. I changed the href value from "#" to "javascript:void();" and it worked! I felt that I was close to a solution! Thank you for all the answers!

Comment: Cool, well if i helped you with your problem do you think you could show your appreciation by marking my answer as useful?

Comment: I would do it but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation as I'm new here...